# how to do cascade delete for foreign key in slick

Tags: scala, slick

In `slick`, how to do cascade deletion for foreign key? Is there any way to specify this on the schema level, or do it when delete is called after the query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I updated the docs: https://github.com/slick/slick/pull/721/

A foreign key constraint can be defined with a Table’s [foreignKey](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0/api/#scala.slick.profile.RelationalTableComponent$Table@foreignKey%5BP,PU,TT%3C:AbstractTable%5B_%5D,U%5D%28String,P,TableQuery%5BTT%5D%29%28%28TT%29%E2%87%92P,ForeignKeyAction,ForeignKeyAction%29%28Shape%5B_%3C:Flat,TT,U,_%5D,Shape%5B_%3C:Flat,P,PU,_%5D%29:ForeignKeyQuery%5BTT,U%5D) method. It first takes a name for the constraint, the referencing column(s) and the referenced table. The second argument list takes a function from the referenced table to its referenced column(s) as well as [ForeignKeyAction](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0/api/#scala.slick.model.ForeignKeyAction$) for onUpdate and onDelete, which are optional and default to [NoAction](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0/api/#scala.slick.model.ForeignKeyAction$$NoAction$). When creating the DDL statements for the table, the foreign key definition is added to it.

```
class Coffees(tag: Tag) extends Table[(String, Int, Double, Int, Int)](tag, "COFFEES") {
  def supID = column[Int]("SUP_ID")
  //...
  def supplier = foreignKey("SUP_FK", supID, suppliers)(_.id, onUpdate=ForeignKeyAction.Restrict, onDelete=ForeignKeyAction.Cascade)
  // compiles to SQL:
  //   alter table "COFFEES" add constraint "SUP_FK" foreign key("SUP_ID")
  //     references "SUPPLIERS"("SUP_ID")
  //     on update RESTRICT on delete CASCADE
}
```

Comment: Is this supposed to work if onDelete is added after the table was already created? It just added it, restarted the server, the table didn't change...